# tar specific files based on a pattern

Tags: shell, files, wildcards, tar

I got a lot of files with the following format:

```
2014_04_01_11.txt
2014_04_01_12.txt
2014_04_01_13.txt
2013_03_25_12.txt
2013_04_29_15.txt
```

I would like to tar all theses files into an archive 20?? _ ?? _ ??**.tar.gz.

My actual command is:

```
find . -name '????_??_??_*.txt' | tar ...
```

I don't know how to define dynamically the name of the archive.

Comment: Ok, now this question just doesn't make sense. Do you want one archive per file or do you have multiple dates and you want and archive for each date as per your comment below.

Comment: @Graeme I have multiple files (year)_(month)_(day)_(hour) and i would like to TAR all these files into an archive (year)_(month)_(day)

Comment: @Graeme, He has multiple files per date. so the question makes sense :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple:

```
tar -cvzf 2014_04_01.tar.gz 2014_04_01_??.txt
```

#### Update

To do this for multiple dates (GNU find):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '????_??_??_??.txt' |
  cut -d_ -f 1-3 |
  sort -u |
  while read date; do
    tar -cvzf "$date".tar.gz "$date"_??.txt
  done
```

Comment: I have also 2013_01_01, 2014_04_25, etc...

Comment: @Greg, updated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash
FIRST=1
unset TARFILE
unset FILESET
find . -name '????_??_??_*.txt' | sort | while read fn
    do
    CURTARFILE=`echo $(basename $fn)|awk -F_ '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3".tar.gz"}'`
    if [ "$CURTARFILE" == "$TARFILE"] ; then
        FILESET=$FILESET" \"$fn\""
        FIRST=0
        continue
    fi
    [ "$FIRST" == "0" ] && tar cfz $TARFILE $FILESET
    $FILESET="\"$fn\""
    FIRST=0
    TARFILE=$CURTARFILE
done
```

Comment: @Greg Are your TXT files stored in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, they could be... (customer)/(year)_(month)_(day)_(hour). However, @Graeme solution works.

Comment: That's why Graeme solution is better, i upvote it :-)